# Cannot overwrite `history` model once compiled

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to save the query but It is giving me error cannot overwrite model once compiled. my models file is

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const history = new mongoose.Schema({
    search_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,

    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("history", history)
```

and my routes file is:

```js
const keys = require("../config/keys")
const Bing = require('node-bing-api')({ accKey: "0112a649fd944630b0954a20ac8c71f6" });
let History = require("../Models/searchhistory")
module.exports = (app) => {

    app.get("/api/imagesearch/:searchname", (req, response) => {

        const query = req.params.searchname
        const per_page = parseInt(req.query.offset, 10)
        Bing.images(query, {
            count: 100,
            offset: 0
        }, (error, res, body) => {
            const hist = new History({

                })
                // hist.save().then(() => {

            // })
            response.send(body)
        })
    })
}
```

I am getting these error when running the code :

```
F:\image abstraction layer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:453
  throw new _mongoose.Error.OverwriteModelError(name);
  ^
```

OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `history` model once compiled.
    at new OverwriteModelError (F:\image abstraction layer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\overwriteModel.js:20:11)
    at Mongoose.model (F:\image abstraction layer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:453:13)
    at Object. (F:\image abstraction layer\Models\searchhistory.js:15:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object. (F:\image abstraction layer\routes\routes.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can solve it by changing that

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("history", history)
```

for that

```
module.exports = mongoose.model.history || mongoose.model("history", history)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be creating the same schema many places and complie them using the same model name
this is not the correct way to do it.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const history = new Schema({
    search_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,

    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    }
})

const History = module.exports = mongoose.model("history", history) // use this History  const to access your history schema every where in your application
```

you can require it using the way you did in your code. but be sure to export your model after compiling.
what's happening here is, you do not export your compiled model.. you just let it compile everytime you make a req. That's why the error occurs.

Comment: Good answer.I tried using wrapping the model export in a function and it worked